# Infering a generic subtype in a function

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
interface myInterface {}

type myInterfaceCreatorFunction<TMyInterface extends myInterface> = (...args: any) => TMyInterface;

declare function test<
    TMyInterfaceCreator extends myInterfaceCreatorFunction<any> = myInterfaceCreatorFunction<any>,
    TMyInterface extends (TMyInterfaceCreator extends myInterfaceCreatorFunction<infer U> ? U : myInterface) = myInterface /** Why is this giving me the error here? */
>(creator: TMyInterfaceCreator): TMyInterface;
```

As the comment states, the second generic parameters default, gives an error:

> Type 'myInterface' does not satisfy the constraint 'TMyInterfaceCreator extends myInterfaceCreatorFunction ? U : myInterface'.(2344)

Based on the signature of `myInterfaceCreator` type, this should work in my opinion, but regardless, this error is not helping me in any way. Why can't I set the default value of `TMyInterface` to `myInterface` type?

If I omit the two default values from the function definition, the function does what I expect it to do, namely, infer the `myInterface` type from the input function, and set the return type accordingly, but I need to be able to set default values to these generics, as I will need other generics in this function too, which I want to define.

Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=24&pln=6&pc=98#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLYE8CS5rycgbwF8AoEsdABxQ20lkQgGEoI4wB7KAMQFcQEYYBxAAeACoBZLDgb4IAD0ggAJgGc0M%20nggA%20ZAF5kACgB05uFADmagFzI4IdAEpD%20qVtyMA3GRUQEABtLFBh%20QWEQZEg1MFESZETkDzovJBY2TihkRWV1TVS5ZlZ2Lj4BIRFRR3R9I1pZHQzSnnDKsRrdABoEpJTGxhylCFUNY37tRmasobyNBsn0kqzyiKrQGGhkAFV9AH4d5HsFtIhXes8i5AB6ACpb5AB1AAt0ZGANMGeP5CtgADdQFY0CgvihoFAuMhntAIAdbtcSLpjAhllx7BNTtMuM4MdJCjpfCQgA)

Comment: With a type parameter like `<X extends Y = Z>` this can only work if `Z` is assignable to `Y` no matter what. If `Z` is possibly not assignable to `Y`, you have an error. Look at [this demonstration](//tsplay.dev/mMMRzm) where the default `MyInterface` is definitely not assignable to the constraint (which is `{a: number}` here). So it's an error. Does that explain why? Or are you still wondering?

Comment: Note that setting default types for generics does not give you type inference.  If you have more generic type parameters, some of which you want to manually specify and others of which you need to have the compiler infer, you cannot get it with defaults.  If that's the real issue then maybe you want to [edit] your question to ask how you can have multiple type parameters, some of which you specify and some of which are inferred for you.  Otherwise this is an [XY Problem](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where you are asking how to do something that wouldn't help even if you could do it.

Comment: @jcalz no, that explains it, I made a mistake there.

Comment: So then would you be satisfied with the above comment/demonstration written up as an answer?

Comment: yes, basically just let me clarify, the problem arises from the fact, that `TMyInterfaceCreator extends myInterfaceCreatorFunction<infer U> ? U : myInterface` will always resolve to something that is AT LEAST a `myInterface`, but may resolve to something, that has additional properties, which are not satisfied by `myInterface` alone, to which I am trying to assign the default value to? if yes, please write an answer, and I will accept it

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a type parameter declaration of the form

```
type Foo<X extends Y = Z> = void;
```

the [type parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) `Z` must definitely meet the [type parameter constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `Y`.  If it is possible that `Z extends Y` is not true, then the compiler will complain, because then when the type parameter falls back to the default, it might fail to meet the required constraint.

In your case,

```
interface MyIFace { }

type MyFunc<T extends MyIFace> = (...args: any) => T;

declare function test<
    C extends MyFunc<any> = MyFunc<any>,
    I extends (C extends MyFunc<infer U> ? U : MyIFace) = MyIFace // error!
>(creator: C): I;
```

the constraint for the `I` type parameter depends on `C`.  We can chose `C` to be such that `MyIFace` is not assignable to this constraint.  For example:

```
// in the following call
test<() => { a: number }>(() => ({ a: 1 }))
// C is ()=>{a: number} and I is MyIFace
// but (C extends MyFunc<infer U> ? U : MyIFace)  evaluates to {a: number}
// and therefore I extends {a: number} is violated.
```

Here we have called `test()` with a `C` type parameter of `() => {a: number}`.  Therefore the constraint `(C extends MyFunc<infer U> ? U : MyIFace)` evaluates to `{a: number}`.  And `MyIFace` cannot be assigned to `{a: number}`, as it is an empty interface and does not contain a known `a` property of type `number`.

So that's the problem; we can choose `C` so that `I` is constrained to almost any particular type we want with as many specific properties as we want, and `MyIFace` is unlikely to have any of these specific properties, so the default is not valid.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAmlC8UDeUCGAuKBnYAnAlgHYDmUAvgNwBQokUAWgsmpjgSRVAEaaECuAWy4Rc5GuGgAxAPbSAPAA0oEAB7AIhACZZYTegD4mAN2n5N1KkXW4AZqgDG0ALIgAkpIfQUZKuLovJPkJ7OQAVZTUNbSgXd09DRAAKADpU1FxiLExUQhAASgRDUItNCHsAG3ToGyD7YHxpQih1HDkqKA6oAGEI9S0dANq5HJAEmJBA4OHc-QAads7XXqidRJ7VPujBqaIbESgAVUMAfkOoTFiPRwLES88oAHoH5VxcaVwAQip9RPtcCFQwHemC6eUwrgsTygRGaAAtqtJyuVpAB3IikeyoJE0CCtRI3QwoDBQfhCfZkH74wpQRJEzAARnIeTyVChPXwqzy8H0SGJpOEuDIaC0UCWHPGcUcrOeXD4wBp60i-XGkxCu32RygpwO5wlVwgBWURixfEBuOa0mQfMEAp8UJymjhIggNne0CWGxWVt4NpEQvFRgalXUmmSQA)